# Connecting to mysql with SUPER user when reached Too many connections

Tags: mysql

The documentation says that:

> mysqld actually permits max_connections+1 clients to connect. The
>   extra connection is reserved for use by accounts that have the SUPER
>   privilege

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

but it doesn't tell how to connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just connect as usual, you just need the SUPER privilege for the connecting account.

Comment: we have root, but still doesn't let us in. we used `mysql -u root`

Comment: Do you use root for normal connections, e.g. from a web server? This would use up the +1 connection.

Comment: No, we have users setup there, but I will verify on a different node.

Comment: Well, I am positive that this normally works like this, had a buggy web app requiring this just last Friday.

Comment: @SvW Mysql allow to connect everybody until `max_connections` has been reached. Then plain users will be refused and super will be granted to make one spare connection, despite of how many super connections are already established.